# Cipher Caesar Shift in Java?

Tags: java

I was trying to simulate the cipher caesar but including numbers and implementing spaces entered by the user.However, when I run this program, the output was not expected. Here is my code, how should I approach this?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class CaesarCipher {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new CaesarCipher();
}

public CaesarCipher() {
    System.out.println("The encoded phrase is: " + encode("s", 0));
}

public String encode(String s,int n) { 
    //get user input for phrase and number shifted;
    Scanner sc =new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a phrase to be encoded:");
    if (sc.hasNextLine()){
    s = sc.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Enter a number to shift each letter/number:");
    n = sc.nextInt();
    }
    sc.close();

    StringBuilder encoded = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i=0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        char letter = (char)(s.charAt(i));  
        int digit = (int)s.charAt(i);

        if (letter >= 'A' && letter <= 'Z') {
            int number = letter - 'A' + n;
            if(number<0)
                number=number+26;
            number=number%26;
            encoded.append((char)(number + 'A'));
        }
        else if(letter >= 'a' && letter <= 'z') {
            int num =  letter - 'a' + n;
            num = num%26;
            encoded.append((char)(num + 'a'));  
        }
        else if (digit>=0 && digit <=9) {
            encoded = 
        }
    }
    return encoded.toString();
}
```

Here is my desirable output:

```
Enter your phrase:
>> 3 cats is nice!
Enter shift for phrase:
>> 1
Your encrypted code is: 4 dbut jt ojdf!
```

Comment: "*`else if (i>=0 && i>=9)`*" - I am quite confident that (one of) the problem(s) lies within this `if` condition. --- For debugging requests, you should always provide a [MCVE], with input, as well as expected and observed output.

Comment: @Turing85 I just edited my post, I was wondering how I can edit "else if (i>=0 && i>=9)" so it accepts numbers?

Comment: Look closely at your code. What does `i` represent? Then, [debug](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) your program.

Comment: should I construct int digit and change I to digit just like how I did with char letter = (char)(s.charAt(i));  ?

Comment: You should [learn to debug your program](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: @Turing85 I just edited my code, but not sure how I should proceed with the number part, does it work in a similar format as the letters?

Comment: Again, debug your program. Getting the character and casting it to `int` will give you the unicode value of the character.

Comment: @Turing85, I think I'm supposed to use letter instead of i right?

Comment: Just try it out! That's the beauty with programming: you can try everything. Making your own mistakes and fixing them has a much better effect on learning than us telling oyu how to do it.

Comment: I just succesfully printed the number, but a little confused how I should print spaces and exclamation point :')

Comment: omg I did it, thank you!